# setThemingColor incorrect on 2D elements

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am using setThemingColor extensively in my viewer app. And it works correctly in 3D. But when I try to use it on a 2D Revit sheet viewable, the color changes slightly but does not match the color code I'm giving it. Bright green comes out as a faded blue, red comes out as brownish, etc. What might be the cause?

Example: This pile cap element should be bright green

[image: Example: This pile cap element should be bright green]

Answer (score 1):

It's working just fine for me, although when i select, it changes color due to selection:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was using a function to convert a hex color code to RGB values. RGB format typically goes from 0-255, but in this case the Vector4 expects values normalized from 0-1